# Problem with install plugins in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: java, plugins, zip, execute, pentaho-data-integration

I have problem with openning and running my sample job that noticing me of missing some plugins: exe_jar_to_variable and job_exe_jar_lib.
Howerver I did search in the marketplace of PDI there was not any of two listed plugins.
Can anyone help me?
I am not allowed to embed my picture so I just share the link.
Thank you in advance!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqCw.png

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but given the names they seem to be java classes made specifically for the job you are trying to run in another installation or version of PDI. You'll need to ask the person who gave you the job to ask what custom-made developments he/she created.

Comment: Yeap. I tried PDI 9.1 but it has the same problem when openning this kinda job.